# how do I send my stringified object to html body

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, express

I send an `html` file to client with `res.write()` method. I also want to send an `object` attached to this `html`.
I tried to `stringify` that object and write it like I wrote the `html` file, but when I do that, my stringified `json object` remains outside of the `html`. I need that json object to be inside of the `html`, so I can parse it with the client side js file.

how should I fix that?

I tried to send it as a `Json object`. but I couldnt get it through the `html`.

```
app.get('/uniform', (req,res) => {
  fs.readFile('uniformflowindex.html', function(err, data) {
    var channelobj = JSON.stringify(channel);
    res.write(data);
    res.write("<div id='objectstring'>" + channelobj + "</div>");
    res.end('');
  });
});
```

it gives the output:

```
<html>

...
my html file
...

</html>

<div id='objectstring'>{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0,"Discharge":20,"FlowDepth":5.......}</div>
```

I just want this `div` to be in `html` file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a wildcard in your html code and then replace the wildcard with your div content.

For example:

```
<html>

...
my html file
...

[[wildcard]]

</html>
```

and then use:

```
app.get('/uniform', (req,res) => {
fs.readFile('uniformflowindex.html', function(err, data) {
var channelobj = JSON.stringify(channel);
res.write(data.replace('[[wildcard]]', "<div id='objectstring'>" + channelobj + "</div>"));
res.end();
})
});
```

Alternatively may not add a wildcard in your html and just replace one of your closing tags such as `<\body>` or `<\html>` with your content + the closing tag itself...

```
app.get('/uniform', (req,res) => {
fs.readFile('uniformflowindex.html', function(err, data) {
var channelobj = JSON.stringify(channel);
res.write(data.replace('</body>', "<div id='objectstring'>" + channelobj + "</div></body>"));
res.end();
})
});
```

Comment: thank you for the opinion. it makes perfect sense. But node js doesn't compile with data.replace method. does it require some npm? (TypeError: data.replace is not a function)

Comment: If anyone else encounters this problem, answer above works perfect. just change data.replace to data.toString().replace.

Answer (score 1):

HTML file:

```
<html>

...
{ content }
...

</html>
```

your code:

```
app.get('/uniform', (req,res) => {
  fs.readFile('uniformflowindex.html', function(err, data) {
    var channelobj = JSON.stringify(channel);
    data = data.replace('{ content }', "<div id='objectstring'>" + channelobj + "</div>");
    res.end(data);
   })
});
```